# Kendo Combo Box Set Default Value

Tags: kendo-ui

I have a kendo combo box with two entries, say "Thing 1" and "Thing 2". I want "Thing 1" to be set by default.

Is there a preferred way to do this? I can't seem to find it, although I did set the placeholder attribute to "Thing 1" and it worked. The Kendo documentation says that placeholder is "The hint displayed by the widget when it is empty. Not set by default." Am I using placeholder incorrectly?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `optionLabel` attribute (which I believe you refer to as the placeholder) is used to specify the text representing no selection. When that is chosen from the list, the selected item is null so is not the correct solution for setting a default, unless you wish the default selection to be `null`. The selection can be set programmatically by calling the `select()` method on the widget instance. The following for example will set the selection to 'Thing1'.

```
<div id="dropdownlist"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#dropdownlist").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: [
                'Thing1',
                'Thing2',
                'Thing3'
            ],
            optionLabel: "None"
    });

    $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList").select(1);
</script>
```

It is worth noting that this is not the only way to achieve this. My above example uses Imperative(JQuery) syntax to declare the dropdown. If you are using the ASP.NET MVC server wrappers, there is a Value attribute you can set in the declaration, for example:

```
.Value("1")
```

Finally, if you are using MVVM with declarative initialization, you can bind the selection to a value on a View Model. I haven't complicated my answer with an MVVM example since I assume you aren't using this mechanism.

Comment: dataSource is zero based, so it should be `$("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList").select(0);` if you want 'Thing1'

Comment: With optionLabel specified, the null entry is the zero index. So in my example, select(1) is actually correct. Without the optionLabel, it would be (0) as you suggest.

Comment: didn't see `optionLabel` there, sorry about that ;)

Answer (score 2):

```
   <script> 

        $(function () {

            var data = [
                { text: "12 Angry Men", value: "1" },
                { text: "Il buono, il brutto, il cattivo.", value: "2" },
                { text: "Inception", value: "3" },
                { text: "One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest", value: "4" },
                { text: "Pulp Fiction", value: "5" },
                { text: "Schindler's List", value: "6" },
                { text: "The Dark Knight", value: "7" },
                { text: "The Godfather", value: "8" },
                { text: "The Godfather: Part II", value: "9" },
                { text: "The Shawshank Redemption", value: "10" },
                { text: "The Shawshank Redemption 2", value: "11" }
            ];

            $("#movies").kendoComboBox({
                dataTextField: "text",
                dataValueField: "value",
                dataSource: data,

            });
            let combobox = $("#movies").data("kendoComboBox");//This "instantiates it"
            combobox.value("The Godfather");


        });

    </script>

<input id="movies" />
```

Result:
[image]